# How can I select a option based on its value and a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a HTML like this:

```
<select id="job" name="job" class="form-control">
    <option value="First Option">First Option</option>
    <option value="Second Option">Second Option</option>
    <option value="Third Option">Third Option</option>
</select>
```

Also I have a PHP variable like this: `$val = "Second Option";`. Now I need to add `selected` attribute to the option that has the same value as `$val` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this: (Better to use ternary condition here)

```
<select id="job" name="job" class="form-control">
    <option value="First Option" <?php echo ($val == "First Option")? "selected":"";?>>First Option</option>
    <option value="Second Option" <?php echo ($val == "Second Option")? "selected":"";?>>Second Option</option>
    <option value="Third Option" <?php echo ($val == "third Option")? "selected":"";?>>Third Option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Vote to close duplicates rather than answering.

Comment: Oh @Satpal, I did think to do so. But as I knew the answer, I posted. Let me vote to close too.